# slidedown jquery problem

Tags: jquery

```
function show_destination(country_id,airport_id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "function.php",
        data: "country_id="+country_id+"&airport_id="+airport_id+"&action=destination",
         beforeSend: function() { $("#loader_destination").html(''); },
        success: function(msg){
            // $(".loader_destination").empty();    
            //$("#destination_div").html(msg);
            //$("#destination_div").slideDown("slow",function(){$("#destination_div").html(msg);})  
            //$("#destination_div").html(msg,function(){$("#destination_div").slideDown("slow");});
            $('#destination_div').slideDown(500, function() { $('#destination_div').html(msg);});

           }
 });

}
```

slideDown this effect not working , 
output simply display , am not find any  effect on display output,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I'd say the element is empty for the 500ms it is supposed to be sliding.
try:

```
$('#destination_div').hide().html(msg).slideDown(500);
```

Comment: you saved my life, your snippet fixed my problem, i learned now..i do better next time, thanks to all...

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the HTML until after the Slidedown has taken effect:

```
$('#destination_div').slideDown(500, function() { 
  $('#destination_div').html(msg);
});
```

You need to switch that up:

```
$('#destination_div').html(msg).slideDown(500);
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

It looks to me like...

```
$('#destination_div').slideDown(500, function() { $('#destination_div').html(msg);});
```

...will slide the DIV down and then set the HTML. If the DIV is empty then you will see no animation.

what about:

```
var $destination_div =  $('#destination_div');
$destination_div.html(msg);
$destination_div.slideDown(500);
```

I'm caching in $destination_div to improve performance, although you could use chaining instead:

```
$('#destination_div').html(msg).slideDown(500);
```

You might even want to augment your beforesend method as well:

```
beforeSend: function() { 
    $("#loader_destination").html(''); 
    $('#destination_div').hide(); 
}
```